# How can I have "Export as CSV" button in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, csv, google-chrome-extension

I created a Chrome extension which scans the page and creates a list of h1-h6 tags of a current page in a popup window. This is how this list looks like for main StackOverflow page:

```
h1 | All Questions
h3 | XmlElement has a list as attribute but its items aren&#39;t separated by comma
h3 | Eclipse, Easily remove/fix all @Override due to Java version change
...
```

I'd like to have an "Export" button, which would give me an ability to save this report in CSV format. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to create a URI storing the CSV content. Then you can create a A element with a [download attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download) set to the desired file name.

If your CSV is really big, you should use [BlobBuilder](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-blobbuilder-interface) and [webkitURL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) instead of data URI scheme to create the link href.

Here is an example using data URI scheme:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.textContent = "Save as CSV";
link.download = "file.csv";
link.href = "data:text/csv,h1;All Questions\n"
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

When the user will click the link, the "file.csv" will be automatically saved in the default Download folder.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17104036/771379) you can find good example for Blob and createObjectURL.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @check_ca answer, I've coded the following to return a csv link element for array data:

```
function getCSVLinkElement(arr){

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.textContent = "Save as CSV";
    link.download = "file.csv";
    var csv = arr.map(function(v){return v.join(',')}).join('\n');
    link.href = encodeURI("data:text/csv,"+csv);

    return link;

}

var el = getCSVLinkElement([['num','sq'],[2,4],[3,9]]);
document.body.appendChild(el);
```