# Convert JavaScript variable value to csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a comma separated variable in my .js file, for example:

```
var out='';
out+="1,val1,val2,val3,val4\n";
out+="2,val1,val2,val3,val4\n";
out+="3,val1,val2,val3,val4\n";
```

I am displaying this value in a browser using `document.write(out);`.
I would like the `out` variable to be downloadable as a `.csv` file.

From data stored in a variable, is there any way to create a csv file and its associated download link in JavaScript?

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravatsinh/57pME/)

Comment: Is that syntax what you want really? All those `valN` strings are useless...Check http://jsbin.com/ifenic/1/edit

Comment: There i no way to do this. Otherwise we would be living in the world with viruses compiling directly in your browser

Comment: i have comma separated value in js file want to save this data as csv

Comment: Well, your syntax doesn't even make sense. Try building your own solution first, look on Google for documentation. When you think you've tried _all_ possible solutions, then come back with the code that failed, post a live example and explain what didn't work. That's how Stackoverflow works; you need to show some effort first.

Comment: @ooops: I think we are living in that world.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski WAIT, OH SHI...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Depends on browser support, but that's getting pretty good with new browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/3fMeL/2/

```
var CSV = [
    '"1","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
    '"2","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
    '"3","val1","val2","val3","val4"'
  ].join('\n');

window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

var contentType = 'text/csv';

var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], {type: contentType});

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'my.csv';
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
a.textContent = 'Download CSV';

a.dataset.downloadurl = [contentType, a.download, a.href].join(':');

document.body.appendChild(a);
```

So the first item is the Blob object, this creates the object that can be downloaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob (http://caniuse.com/#search=blob)

The next part is the download attribute of the link, which informs the browser to download the CSV file rather than opening it in the browser window. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: Thank you very much! is this possible without link (download csv link)?

Comment: @RSSisodiya You can create a link and fire the click event on it.  You need a link to take advantage of the download attribute.  If you put the URL directly in to the browser `window.location.href` it will just open, and not download.

Answer (score -1):

there is jquery plugin for output file at the client side without server side interaction,

https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify