# Downloading JS excel variable as a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I'm currently struggling with downloading an excel file, created and filled at servlet.

If i use `window.location.replace("URL")` to go to the server side, i can get the download dialog without a problem, i can create and return file easily. But this isn't enough for me because i also  need to return error codes in some situations.

Now i'm trying to go to the server side using

```
        $.get(webContextPath + "/backend_url", function(data, status){
             //do stuff
        });
```

and i get the excel file i created as a javascript variable (called data). Now the problem is, how can i trigger the downloading dialog ? I've been searching a lot, found some examples with .csv files but i've failed when i tried to use them in my situation.

PS: I've also tried Blob and failed miserably.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `data` is csv string right?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat no, its an .xlsx file. I’ve found ‘downloading variable’ examples for csv’s only. It’s kinda irrelevant for my problem.

Comment: *How* did the Blob fail, though?  Ignoring the CSV data in a JS Variable part, once you have the Blob with the data you want, the triggering of the download should work, like in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103398/convert-javascript-variable-value-to-csv-file/17104036#17104036)... So what does 'failed miserably' actually mean?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you tag this with both Java and JavaScript? You do realize that these are unrelated languages, right?