# Blob is appending commas in typescript, when creating csv file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, csv

I'm trying to export data from an Angular 6 web application.

I have an array of string, where each string is a csv line, formatted like this:

```
var csvLines = ['val1,val2\n', 'val3,val4\n'...];
```

Once I've added all the data to i need to the array, i write it to the console:

[image]
This looks fine...

Now i wan't to convert it to a blob and download it as a .CSV file.

The download is fine, but the format of the output is wrong.

When I run the following code:

```
          const blob = new Blob([csvLines], {type: 'text/csv;encoding:utf-8'});
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = () => {
            console.log(reader.result);
          };
          reader.readAsText(blob);
```

I get this output.

**NOTE** the commas that are appended on every line but the first - this mess up my csv.
[image]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and perhaps how to disable the comma appending?

I have tried to create the Blob with `text/plain` as mimetype and without the encoding, but the commas are still appended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JavaScript variable value to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103398/convert-javascript-variable-value-to-csv-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing `csvLines` as `[csvLines]` to `new Blob(..)`, you are passing an array containing an array. It seems like the subarray is joined using commas.
Just use `new Blob(csvLines, { type: 'text/csv;encoding:utf-8' });` and you should be fine.

```
const csvLines = ['val1,val2\n', 'val3,val4\n'];
const blob = new Blob(csvLines, { type: 'text/csv;encoding:utf-8' });
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  console.log(reader.result);
};
reader.readAsText(blob);
```