# Generating a CSV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, csv

I successfully am generating a CSV using Javascript. I want to have two lines in the final CSV - one header and one data line.

Here is my code for generating the header.

```
  var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,participant_id,age,gender,country_live_longest,country_musical_enculturation,lyric_language,favorite_genre,years_formal_training,understood_yes_or_no,media_shown,";
  for (var i = 0; i < randomized.length; i++) {
    csvContent += "arousals_"+ i.toString() +",valences_"+ i.toString() +","
  }
  csvContent = csvContent.slice(0, -1);
  csvContent += '\r\n';
```

After this it's a simple string append with comma separated values.
However, when I check the string getting built it stops being downloadable after the new line or after any spaces.

This is what it looks like in console.

[image]

Anything in red is not part of the CSV downloadable file.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Replacing with just ```\n``` instead of ```\r\n``` didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using blob API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.
Here is an example [Convert JavaScript variable value to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103398/convert-javascript-variable-value-to-csv-file)