# How to download a to-do list to your device

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

so I made a to-do list with Vue.js https://justintownsend.github.io/todo.html
Anyway, say if I was the user, and I made my to-do list, and I wanted to save (download) the list to my device. I've tried using  Save . But it doesn't work.
If anybody can help me out with this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Without more specifics, I'd venture a guess you could solve this using blobs and files, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17104036/1161948

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution using [`jsPDF`](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) HTML5 client and jQuery, it captures the current page and generates a pdf file which is automatically downloaded to the user's system.

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('my-todos.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Test content-->
<h1> My TODO List</h1>

<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```